# Filter query by the last row of a left join

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I have a query that returns all Parcels, it looks like this:

```
Parcel.createQueryBuilder('parcel')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('parcel.events', 'events')
  .orderBy({ 'events.timestamp': 'ASC' })
  .getMany()
  .then(parcels => this.res.send(parcels))
  .catch((err: Error) => this.res.status(500).send({ error: err.message }));
```

I'm trying to filter the result based on the value of the column `category` of the last row from the `events` join.

The model for `events` looks like this:

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@Column()
category: string;

@Column()
title: string;

@Column({ nullable: true })
details?: string;

@Column()
location: string;

@Column({
  type: 'timestamp with time zone',
  default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
})
timestamp: string;

@ManyToOne(() => Parcel)
parcel: Parcel;
```

I've tried many things and none seem to work, my last attempt was this:

```
Parcel.createQueryBuilder('parcel')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('parcel.events', 'events')
  .leftJoinAndSelect(qb => qb.subQuery()
    .select(['"parcelId"', 'category', 'timestamp'])
    .from(ParcelEvent, 'event')
    .orderBy({ timestamp: 'DESC' })
    .limit(1), 'lastEvent', '"lastEvent"."parcelId" = parcel.id')
  .orderBy({ 'events.timestamp': 'ASC' })
  .where('"lastEvent"."category" = :status', { status })
  .getMany()
  .then(parcels => this.res.send(parcels))
  .catch((err: Error) => this.res.status(404).send({ error: err.message }));
```

I'm a bit new to SQL in general too, so that doesn't really help me much in solving this.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with a minimal example?

Comment: `I'm trying to filter the result based on the value of the column category of the last row from the events join.` Leaves room for interpretation. Please provide an unambiguous objective.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Sorry for taking so long to respond. I'm trying to filter out all parcels that don't match an input based on the last value of the column `category` in `events`. For example, if the input is "delivered" I want to get only the parcels where the last `event` has  "delivered" as its `category`. I hope that makes sense.